# VB.NET 2010 - IDE - Run/Pause/Stop Buttons missing

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ide

Very strange one ... today I loaded up VS 2010 to work on a VB.NET project .... but for some reason the Run/Pause/Stop buttons are missing from the toolbar and I cannot set breakpoints.

Only changes from yesterday to my system was this morning Windows was trying to install Visual Studio SP1 updates but all failed.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you right-click the toolbar and checked "Debug" item?

Comment: Yep, it just shows the Add/Remocve button droplist but no mention of the Run buttons etc

Answer (score 3):

[image]

this menu comes up when you right-click a blank space on the toolbar. I don't know if you could see that. The Debug toolbar is enabled by the item immediately below the highlighted option

And you can still use shortcuts and Debug menu to perform your task

```
F9 - Break Point
F5 - Run
Ctrl+Alt+Break - Pause
and so on
```

Comment: Unfortunately the function keys for run/debug etc do nothing

Selecting Debug from the menu has no effect.

Comment: TRying a repair now and if not then reinstall

Answer (score 0):

Ran a Repair on the installation and that resolved the issue.